# Vue intializing user store

Tags: vue.js, authentication, store

I have a module `auth` in my vuex store. There I want to store my user object (containing accesstoken, ...) Using the store, I can easily using store getters ask anywhere in my application whether user is logged in etc...

I also store user information (accessToken, etc...) in `localStorage` in order to handle user coming back after closing application and user is still "logged in" (i.e. token is still valid).

My question is: When user refreshes page, my `beforeEach` function is the first thing that is called. But at that time my user store has not been filled yet. So my

`let loggedIn = store.getters['auth/isLoggedIn'];` in `beforeEach` returns false.

I have adde in `App.vue` `beforeMount`:

```
if (JSON.parse((localStorage.getItem("user") || '{}'))) {
      //This is the mutation to the user store
      this.SET_USER(JSON.parse((localStorage.getItem("user") || '{}')));
```

But this is called **after** `beforeEach` in `router` has already been executed. So at what place in my application should I place:

```
if (JSON.parse((localStorage.getItem("user") || '{}'))) {
      this.SET_USER(JSON.parse((localStorage.getItem("user") || '{}')));
```

So the user store is correctly filled right at the beginning?

Comment: I use vue-persistedstate package. it shares states between vuex and localstorage on page refresh.

Comment: i would hook on "created()" and not on "beforeMount". created triggers earlier. but as @mohammad suggested i would use  local storage or the 
https://github.com/robinvdvleuten/vuex-persistedstate

Comment: Yes I will switch to `vue-persistedstate` because also `created` is not called before `beforeEach`